# Can mathematica give an approximate solution of some function

Tags: equation-solving

I wish to solve this function for `PCOAL`.

```
q == (0.0238849 PCOAL + 0.903548 PCOAL^1.86)
```

If an algebraic solution is not possible, I'd like to ask Mathamatica for an approximation, `PCOAL = something_without_PCOAL / q`

Comment: Have you looked up `Solve` in the documentation?

Comment: In principle, `Solve` is the right approach, but it yields 93 solutions.  In most cases, all but one of these are complex.  So, the question is, which of these is desired?

Comment: @Jens I have seen you voted to put this question on hold. Well, can be that it is formulated not in the best way, however, even in the current version it seems to be more deep than first impression shows. Note that OP asks for the *approximation* of the solution, not the solution itself. In fact these kind of equations can be solved analytically in terms of hypergeometric functions, see for instance this paper M.L.Glasser http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002879

Comment: @yarchik There was ample time to clarify the question, I think. After all, I asked a question and didn't get a reply.

Comment: @Jens yes, this is a valid argument.

Comment: Thanks, yes Solve doesn't work well for this or more complicated instances, so an approximation might be best.

Answer (score 3):

Let us write `p` instead of `PCOAL` for the sake of shortness, and first let us plot your equation at, say, `q=0.5`:

```
 Plot[{0.5, (0.0238849*p + 0.903548 p^1.86)}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["p", Italic, 16], Style["q", Italic, 16]}]
```

Here is the result:
[image]

You get, thus, a single solution which is roughly close to `q^1/2`. It can be now obtained numerically using the `FindRoot` routine:

```
lst = Table[{q, 
   FindRoot[0.0238849*p + 0.903548 p^1.86 == q, {p, Sqrt[q] // N}][[1,
      2]]}, {q, 0, 1, 0.1}]

(*  {{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.294456}, {0.2, 0.432039}, {0.3, 0.539891}, {0.4, 
  0.632052}, {0.5, 0.71406}, {0.6, 0.788786}, {0.7, 0.857954}, {0.8, 
  0.922694}, {0.9, 0.983794}, {1., 1.04183}}  *)
```

This solution may be then fitted to some analytical function entitled "model":

```
model = a*q^0.6 + b*q;
ff = FindFit[lst, model, {a, b}, q]


(*  {a -> 1.22995, b -> -0.190771}  *)
```

we can visually check the fit quality as follows:

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["q", Italic, 16], Style["p", Italic, 16]}],
  Plot[model /. ff, {q, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

yielding

[image]

Done. Have fun!

Comment: This works too: `s = p /. First@Solve[q == (0.0238849 p + 0.903548 p^1.86), p]; Plot[s, {q, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]`.

Answer (score 3):

Let us make your equation little bit more general:

```
q == a x + b x^p
```

or

```
q - a x==b x^p
```

where in your case

```
a=0.0238849; 
b=0.903548;
p=1.86;
```

One can find a progression of approximations for $x$ (PCOAL) in your case by the following recursion:

```
z[0] = (q/b)^(1/p);
Table[z[i] = (q - b (1 - p) z[i - 1]^p)/(b p z[i - 1]^(p - 1) + a);
 z[i], {i, 3}]
```

This is kind of the Newton method. In most of the cases the zeroth order approximation is sufficient, i.e. `x=z[0]`. For more precision you can take `x=z[1]` which explicitly means `x=(p q)/(a + p (b/q)^(1/p) q)` . This is already quite accurate.

> PCOAL=(1.86 q)/(0.0238849 + 1.76129 q^0.462366)

Comment: Thank you!  sorry I went away for a day, these suggestions seem very responsive and I will check into them now!