# Plot of complicated Root function fails depending on PerformanceGoal

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Problem introduced in Version 11.0, reported as CASE:3708213, fixed in Version 11.0.1.**

An alternative solution to [125561](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125561/1063) is

```
s = p /. First@Solve[q == (0.0238849 p + 0.903548 p^1.86), p];
```

a `Root` function with `LeafCount` of `458`.  It can be plotted without difficulty by

```
Plot[s, {q, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Table[s, {q, 0, 1, .001}], DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

produces almost the same plot, omitting a few points at very small `q`, where `s` evaluates to `Indeterminate`; e.g.,

```
Position[Table[s, {q, 0, 1, .0001}], Indeterminate]
(* {{6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {11}, {16}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {25}, {27}} *)
```

On the other hand,

```
Plot[s, {q, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

runs about 20 minutes, returning a blank chart.  The much less demanding

```
Plot[s, {q, .9, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

does the same.  Why?

**Addendum**

[Feyre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7312/feyre) observed in a comment below that `Plot` with `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` ran fine on Ver 10.4, which I just confirmed with Ver 10.4.1.  Perhaps, Ver 11.0, which I used above, has introduced a bug.

Comment: Failed to reproduce `Debian Stable`,`10.4`, all run fine.

Comment: @Feyre  Many thanks.  I should have thought to check this behavior for 10.4.1, for which it works fine.  But, not 11.0!  Bug, perhaps.

Comment: Very strange: Fast: `Plot[(foo = 0; s), {q, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 0, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]`.  Slow: `Plot[(s), {q, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 0(*, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"*)]`, with or without `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`; it appears to hang before the function is evaluated (use `foo++` instead of `foo = 0` or `EvaluationMonitor`), although it could have started to evaluate it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Reap[Plot[(s), {q, .9, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[s]]]` takes 20 minutes to `Sow` 10 evaluations of `s` and yields a plot with no curve.  Adding `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` reduces runtime to a negligible amount, `Sow`s the same values, and gives a correct curve.

Comment: 20+ min. to first evaluation, then all done in less than a second: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hzO3r.png

Comment: It probably has occurred to you, but if not, I think this should be reported. Even if someone argues the time delay is not enough of a backslide to be considered a bug, the failure to produce a plot certainly is.  I'll tag it so, but I'm not really sure how to tell when community consensus is reached.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I agree that community consensus is an ambiguous concept, so I usually wait a day before reporting what I believe to be a bug.  With a consensus of two, I shall report it soon.  Thanks for adding the tag.

Comment: Adding the option `Exclusions -> None` fixes things for me.

Comment: @ChipHurst Do you think that the numerical instability of `s` causes the exclusions to effectively wipe out the plot? And is the time spent analyzing exclusions?  And I think `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` entails `Exclusions -> None`, so that might be counted as an "explanation" for the difference.

Comment: @ChipHurst  Indeed, it does.  A good workaround for what appears to be a bug.  Thanks,

Comment: @MichaelE2  Are you suggesting that `Plot` searches for computed exclusions before beginning to evaluate the function at the points to be used in the curve?  That would be horribly inefficient.  Why compute points for an exclusion search and then not use them in the curve?  I should add that `Exclusions -> "Discontinuities"` acts like Exclusions -> "None", but `Exclusions -> "Singularities"` acts like not using `Exclusions`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, and 20+ min. means it's doing something inefficiently.  What if it is searching for singularities analytically? -- I think `Exclusions -> "Classic"` uses the "classic" exclusions code, whatever that is.

Comment: @MichaelE2  `Plot[s, {q, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  Exclusions -> All] // AbsoluteTiming` shows that the problem is, indeed, associated with `Exclusions`.

Comment: See if you agree with my answer.  Perhaps tagging it [tag:bugs] was premature after all.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Problem fixed in 11.0.1.  Thanks for all your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One part of the problem lies in the computation of `Exclusions`.  Another part is in the use of the computed exclusion criterion in the construction of the plot; I do not understand this part fully.  The connection with `PerformanceGoal` is found in the docs for [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html):

> `Exclusions -> Automatic` is effectively equivalent to `Exclusions -> All` if `$PerformanceGoal` is `"Quality"`, and to `Exclusions -> None` otherwise.

First, to compute the exclusions of `Root[f, k]`, which may have discontinuities at branch points, `Plot` essentially computes

```
Resultant[f[x], f'[x], x]
```

For the `Root` in `s`, we get, after about 20 minutes or so,

```
resultant = Resultant[s[[1, 1]], D[s[[1, 1]], #], #];
Short[resultant, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That's kind of a whopper, both in degree and in coefficients.  You can see this in the exclusion computed, if you're willing to wait another 20 min., with this:

```
Visualization`ExpandExclusions[s, {q}, Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I think this explains the 20 minute wait for the plot.

As for the second part, it seems to me one might expect numerical difficulties.  The left-hand side of the resultant does not evaluate to machine-size reals for `q` between `0.9` and `1`, and `Plot` coordinates have to be (smaller than) machine reals (`Plot[$MaxMachineNumber/100000*x, {x, 0, 10}]` v. `Plot[$MaxMachineNumber/10000*x, {x, 0, 10}]`).  Perhaps exclusions are computed at machine precision and overflow is treated as `Infinity`.  This is just a guess, though.

Bug or not? I used to think it was, but it seems like an improvement to handling `Root` objects was added, which has some consequences.  On the plus side, `Plot` does not connect the jumps in a `Root[]`.  It would be nice to be able to control it. There might be a time constraint on computing exclusions, or maximum degree for `Root[]`.  In this case the coefficients of `s` are greater than `$MaxMachineNumber`, which could be taken as an indicator to skip computing exclusions.

In any case, I think the standard answer should be to use `Exclusions -> None` for plotting a complicated `Root[]` when plotting it takes a long time.

Comment: Thank you for lavishing such careful attention on this question (+1).  Although `s[[1]]` has numerous branch cuts, `Root[...,1]` shows no evidence of crossing from one branch to another.  Also, I computed `ss = Series[s, {q, .8, 3}] // Normal`, which agreed well with `s` for `q > .5`.  Mathematica also warned me that the expansion might be on the wrong branch, but it was not.  So, although your explanation of why `Plot` is so slow in this instance seems very plausible, I continue to believe that failure to plot a curve is a bug.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You're welcome...I'm not saying that branches of `s` affect the graph; I agree that they do not.  I'm saying the issues are (1) that `s` is a `Root` object, which entails branch checking, and (2) that the larger-than-machine-real values of the resultant used in checking for branches might overflow yielding an IEEE infinity and might be interpreted as a singularity. The overflow has nothing to do with jumping branches. -- BTW, I got the `Resultant[]` from this: `Trace[TimeConstrained[Plot[s, {q, 0.9, 1}], 0.2], _Resultant, TraceInternal -> True]`, but it's inconsistent.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Another bit of proof: `Block[{Resultant}, Resultant[___] := 1; Plot[s, {q, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]`...just playing...